# Show part of next slides in ionic2/swiper slider

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, swiper.js

I am using Ionic2 slider which is using the Swiper under the hood. I have built a carousel that shows 3 at a time but I would like the fourth slide to show partly so the user knows there is more slides (can't use pagination dots). I can't see any configuration (either on Ionic API or Swiper API) to achieve. Is anyone aware of a configuration or a "non-hacky" way of achieving this. I have attached screenshot of what the design is suppose to look.

[image]

Comment: Could you create a simple plunker with the code, so we can take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the template ...

```
<ion-slides [options]="sliderOptions"> ... <
```

And in your `.ts` class ...

```
export class ClassWithSlider {

  // slider options
  sliderOptions = {
    slidesPerView:4,
    centeredSlides:true
  };

}
```

The reference for the options can be found [here](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.V9KT5jszzbE), in section **Swiper Parameters**.